# Creating binding source vs just assigning a List<C> for combobox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the following link, the author shows how to create a binding source and add sorting function to a grid view. It should work similarly for combobox datasource. However does it have any benefit to do it for simpler controls like combobox or listbox? I can just assign a list of type `List<AClass>` and then assign the DisplayMember and Value for the controls.

http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2008/06/binding-domain-objects-in-visual-studio.html

Even for data grid view, does it work well for complex situation like, for example, sorting on a grid view with paging? Looks the class `PropertyComparerCollection` in the example only works the loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

The article is focused on binding complex business objects to the grid view. This has been a intensively debated subject since .Net Framework 2.0. If the properties of your bound type are no longer primitive, then you have to get your hands dirty to support sorting, filtering or searching.

There are plenty generic classes for this goal, but I would recommend [this implementation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blw/), with a nice video demo [here](http://blw.sourceforge.net/demo.html).

However, if you're not aiming at a data grid view, but rather at a combo box or list box, **and wish not to modify the underlying store while sorting or filtering**, you could still use a custom class derived from *IBindingListView* and *BindingList(of T)*, like the one suggested above and manually call *ApplySort* or *ApplyFilter*. The implementation in the article linked in your post and the one I suggested use temporary copies of the original data source for sorting/filtering.

Furthermore, for paging instead of taking slices out of the original data source, you'd be taking slices out of the wrapped sortable view of that data source.